# Why is Santa so jolly all of the time?

Tags: santa-claus

We know that he brings presents to all the [girls and boys](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13495/how-can-santa-exist-when-adults-buy-the-toys?noredirect=1&lq=1), lives at the north pole and brings happiness and festive cheer to people all over the world.

He is also perpetually joyful. He is always smiling and laughing and bringing cheer to others. But, when you think about it, he doesn't really have a lot to be happy about himself.

He lives in isolation in one of the most remote regions known to man, with only the company of elves and reindeer. His home is in one of the coldest places on earth, a place that a lot of the time is in almost perpetual darkness. Even his [very existence is doubted](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63416/who-is-spreading-the-rumour-that-santa-isnt-real) by most people.

He works hard 364 days a year to provide all of the deserving children of the world with toys and gifts, and on the remaining day he has to [bend the laws of time and space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/32007/how-do-santa-and-the-reindeer-survive-delivery-night?rq=1) just to do his job.

On top of all of this, he has to pore over the naughty and nice list to decide who deserves to be delivered to and who doesn't. He is the judge and the jury, and has to live with the weight of the tears of all of the poor children who only get coal in their stocking.

Even the good part of his job, delivering presents to the good children, he only gets to do on one day of the year, and he doesn't even get to experience their joy and gratitude up close.

So how can he keep smiling for the rest of the time? When December 26th comes around, how does he keep on going knowing how much time is ahead of him before he gets to be happy again?

What is the secret to Santa's happiness?

Comment: _"He works hard 364 days a year to provide all of the deserving children of the world with toys and gifts"_... Well, according to the most voted answer to the post you've linked in the very first paragraph, that is not the case, but it's even worse: he's bored-to-death for most of those 364 days!

Comment: You know the magic dust he gave to the reindeer?  Santa likes to dip into the stash himself.

Comment: This seems entirely about the motivations of a particular character and not about building a world.

Comment: Ugh, I guess it's that time of year. Everyone get ready for the endless inane Santa posts that people think are "fun" but don't actually provide any Worldbuilding usefulness.

Comment: Like the jingle says. Things go better with coke.

Comment: Hmm ... the jolly Santa is s recent invention. The historical personage he is based on,  Bishop Nicholas of Myra,  is generally pictured as a somber ascetic. He is remembered for his generosity and courage in the face of serious persecution,  and is considered the patron saint of children and sailors (among others). We commemorate his habit of giving anonymous gifts yearly at Christmas.

Comment: The recent invention of a 'jolly' Santa Claus notwithstanding (see pojo-Guy's comment), don't underestimate the power of food. All those sugary biscuits and fruit mince pies et al are going to lift his spirits and there is plenty of evidence that sugar in particular has a mood altering effect. For some people, the sugar they put in their coffee is just as important as the caffeine. Like a friend of mine used to say, 'When was the last time you saw a chubby terrorist?' That said, there's a reason why the jolly fat man is a stereotype.

Answer (score 5):

Santa delivers to all the children in the world, whom all leave him a [schooner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schooner_(glass)) of sherry and a [mince pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mince_pie) which is at least 20% proof.

I believe that he then spends Dec 26th to approx October 31st with the worse hangover and heartburn known to existence.

Between November 1st and December 23rd he has to get the elves, who have spent the entire time he was recovering singing [bad karaoke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azMeDD9N8eY&list=PLkbAbYQazp0j2vqwwsPAG6q2jmUtg2Abq) rather then doing the job they're paid for of making all the presents he is expecting to give out on Christmas Eve/Day.

He also has to get the reindeer, all of whom have been happily procreating most of there off season, back in to the program and retrained in to pulling a sleigh.  All except Rudolf who, as his red nose points to his own abuse issues, [has to be broken out of rehab](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhdEKY1b0tk), again.

Come's Christmas Eve night, where Santa will once again drink too much sherry and comfort eat his own weight, including sleigh, of mince pies due to the stress of dealing with a bunch of karaoke singing pointy eared [c**kwombles](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cockwomble) who can't just do they're damn jobs..

Comment: Does he REALLY deliver to Jewish homes?

Comment: @JustinThyme Yes, yes he does, after that much sherry he'll deliver to the ISS..

Answer (score 1):

Santa some how has to determine if kids are naughty or nice. He knows this because he is always watching. So I think it would be safe to assume that he can watch (or record) people.

Santa gets his happiness from watching people enjoy their presents and spend time with their families. Much like people enjoy watching heartfelt films or comedies. He can continue to the next year knowing that he will do it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

*Because the basic emotions are positive vectors and people are inclined towards positive emotions as compared to negative emotions over time.*

One of **the evidence** is the inclination towards wearing red clothing:

There are four psychological primary colours - red, blue, yellow and green. They relate respectively to the body, the mind, the emotions and the essential balance between these three.

The RED. Physical
Positive: Physical courage, strength, warmth, energy, basic survival, 'fight or flight', stimulation, masculinity, excitement. 
Negative: Defiance, aggression, visual impact, strain.

Comment: Traditionally he wore green, or was an elf like figure or a bishop or furs depending on which culture, the fat man in a red suit is from the very successful Coke adverts of the 1930's painted by Haddon Sundblom