# How will Jesus Christ judge billions of people at the end of the world?

Tags: internal-consistency, religion, futurology

Imagine after we die, for an unpredictable future, I wonder in what manner Jesus Christ would judge us. Even without accounting the population of dead who will be raised up at the Last Judgment, we now have more than 7 billions living people on earth. It is estimated that we have about 107 billion people who have ever lived.

I wonder at the time of the General Resurrection, and at the final Judgment, that how Jesus Christ will judge all of us. According to Scripture, every individual of the human race will have to appear before the judgment seat, Eccl. 12:14; Matt. 12:36, 37; 25:32; Rom. 14:10; II Cor. 5:10; Rev. 20:12.

With that being said, all the parties including the demons will also be judged and the duration of the judgment cannot be determined. Some assert it will be a day of a thousand years.For e.g., it is likely to take millions of years even if it could finish judging a person within an hour.

Below is the simple math calculating the duration to judge 100 billion people.

> (100,000,000,000 / 24 ) / 365 = 11415525.11415525

That is more than 10 million years guys!

So my question is,

Will all of us (including demons) have to be at the hearing while being judged one by one? Or is it going to happen concurrently? Or will it be broken down to a singularity?

Let me explain it further according to Scripture: 
Rev. 20:12 (The Final Judgment)

> And I saw the dead, great and small, standing before the throne. And
>   there were open books, and one of them was the book of life. And the
>   dead were judged according to their deeds, as recorded in the books.

II Cor. 5:10 (Good and Bad Fruit)

> For we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ, so that
>   each of us may receive what is due us for the things done while in the
>   body, whether good or bad.

Does it suggest that we, all nations (billions of people with different languages) have to be present and standing before the throne at the same time in order to listen to every details of each person's good or bad deeds including the verdict and the pronouncement to be transcribed?

Is there any supporting Scripture that describes there will be a common language or any sort of advanced intelligence available for all of us starting from the time of the Judgement?

> Note: This question has already been asked in
>   [christianity.stackexchange.com](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) a month ago but was removed after
>   a few hours. It did receive some answers and positive feedbacks and
>   one of the answers suggests "There is no Scripture that supports the
>   theology."

When considering it from the audience's perspective, will every verdict or pronouncement for all good and bad deeds made by billions of people be acknowledged by our poor intelligence? or is it not necessary to acknowledge other's deeds at all?

Please shed me some light.

Comment: Remember, we are mostly Worldbuilders, so we can come up with non-scripture related solutions. If you are seeking for scripture related explanation, consider asking this on [Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30978/anatomically-correct-santa/30988#30988).  Consider that this universe is to the Jewish God as a VR world is to us.

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/ ¿?

Comment: @Theraot already tried there, they just didn't accept my question.

Comment: @kolunar here - judging by the current answers - it risks to fall to opinion based - for instance I do believe the answer is "It doesn't matter".

Comment: He will use parallel computations.

Comment: Upvoted, because I saw a recent trending to downvote (by someone) every question I put an answer on, so I needed to balance the -1 with a +1.

Comment: @DarioOO While there is no enforcement mechanism in place, voting to cancel out someone else's vote is not a recommended practice. You should be voting on the merits of the question itself.

Comment: @user6760 You're only partially right. Problem is, I can think of three religions that say all non-believers are going to Hell. So everyone is going to Hell.

Comment: @Frostfyre Everyone except for mormons, accoring to South Park.

Comment: Kolunar, welcome to the site. As Pavel mentioned, Worldbuilding isn't about one religion or another; the Christianity SE is the appropriate place for Scripture-centric questions. If this is for a story, and you can't find your answer in Scripture (or by asking the local clergy), feel free to make it up.

Comment: @Frostfyre you are right, but Luck should not allow people to downvote at same time I Put an answer. I do not vote to cancel other's downvotes, I do that only when the downvote could be attributed wrongly to me (which is happening very often resulting in retaliation against me which is evern worst), and anyway I don't think this questionis bad and could as well deserve an upvote or two ^^

Comment: @Frostfyre, Judaism doesn't really have a hell to send anyone to, culturally one was tagged in later but it never properly caught on the way it did with the Christians.

Comment: The book of revelations is an allegorical discussion on the persecution of Christians...not a story of the future.

Comment: @James It's not about the book of revelations, it's about the future after we die. I have been trying to construct the imaginary world after death.

Comment: The judgment is insanely quick.  clothes woven of two materials?  Hell for you!  Red meat on friday, hell for you!  Are you disabled or wounded?  Hell for you!  "Whosoever … hath any blemish, let him not approach to offer the bread of his God. For whatsoever man he be that hath a blemish, he shall not approach: a blind man, or a lame, or he that hath a flat nose, or any thing superfluous... He shall not go in unto the vail, nor come nigh unto the altar, because he hath a blemish; that he profane not my sanctuaries. Leviticus 21:17-23 KJV"

Answer (score 11):

Differently

Humans cannot in any way imagine or understand the actual things happening. The passages quoted describe a vision that uses human concepts (books, judgement halls, waiting in a line, etc) to make it intelligible to humans.

There is no point in calculating the implications of what are only symbols, not physically accurate observations.

Answer (score 9):

Consecutively

A few hundred million years is meaningless in an eternal afterlife. You're going to be there a *long* time, you might as well get used to the slower pace of (non)existence while standing in the queue waiting to get in.

**When compared to eternity, any finite amount of time ceases to have meaning.**

Answer (score 8):

Concurrently.

Jesus referred here is part of the trinity, not the human and mortal version, similarly the judgement does not really happen in this world. Thus the individual judgements all happen at the same time and place.

But yeah, if you want details of the theology, this probably isn't the place.

Comment: My thought exactly.

Answer (score 0):

- Realistically put, if someone is able to hear all the prays in the world it would be no problem to him also judging all of us. If he is a intradimensional being, **time has no significance for him**. What it would be millions of years for us, could be just a blink of his eyes.
- Maybe once we dies times go very fast for us and very slow for Jesus? So once we died we just see the end of the world and already know how we were judged and he has all the time to do his counting?
- Maybe we all know how we will be judged (deeply in our hearth), and hence Jesus just need to take the answer out of us (and that will be a really quick process). In example every non-sensic downvoter know how he will be judged, there's no need to dig into his downvotes history.

Also some ironic explainations came to my mind.

**Less work to do.**

Let Satana corrupt all people so they kill good people only, who died is automagically innocent, who survived is evil and hence automagically guilty. If there are few survivors it won't be much long judge everyone.

**Playing dices.**

Ok here's the next 1000 people. Let's roll a 2d500 (note Jesus' dices are magic) to see who's guilty and who's not. I can roll 30 dices per minute so it is 15000 people per minute. Wich are 7 133 333 minutes = 13,5 years.. Assuming Jesus works 8 hours a day and 5 days a week then that's in reality 30 years.. ouch!. The world is going to end when the work for judgeing all us becomes 33 years, 3 months, 3 days 3 hours and 3 minutes. (We don't have much time left!)

**Santa's already did the counting**

Maybe hard work already done by third parties?

Comment: The answer was a Work in Progress, you are still in time to turn downvotes into upvotes and save your soul.

Comment: I'm not fond of downvoting and probably they are the first batch to enrol to hell however god does not play dice!

Comment: lol your comment is epic XD. Einstein too could not believe God's playing dices, but we are not given to know soo.

Comment: Not only does this answer provide more insight than other, higher voted answers, it also does so in a WorldBuilding mindset. I am surprised it is the lowest voted answer, and even more surprised it was negative. It also has some humor; come on, so many people make such a big deal about Santa every year, and we get songs on the radio at that time about how Santa is judging if we're naughty or nice - this would have been upvote-worthy even as a 1-liner had it been just the Santa comment.