#  How to deliver each kid a toy in this night?

Tags: travel, transportation, santa-claus, logistics

**HO, HO, HO**, fellow worldbuilders. My name is Nicholaus, or simply Claus. However, most people will call me Santa.

I am the owner of a toy factory in the North Pole ☃. It is in the North's coast of Greenland, to be precise. It is simply the largest toy factory in the world. Each year, my <s>slaves</s>, ops, I meant to say, **workers**, produce a toy for every kid  in the planet, for free <s>(I don't pay them)</s>.

Each kid should receive his/her toy, already properly packaged,  yearly in December, at the midnight of the day 24 to 25 in local time . Getting it earlier or later by no more than one hour is ok, but since I have to obey strict SLA protocols, nothing can be delivered before 11:00 PM of day 24 or after 01:00 AM of day 25.

My problem is logistic. I am the only person in this world who can deliver the toys, I can't delegate it to anybody else. My vehicle is a flying sled pulled by 12 reindeers.  And I should be able to do all my billions deliveries in around 24 hours (getting advantage from Earth's rotation). My sled should be pretty fast and each delivery should be done pretty quickly.

**What procedures should I follow in order to be able to deliver a toy to every kid in the world around local midnight on the Christmas night? How would I am be able to do that?**

Comment: Breakdown is here: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30978/anatomically-correct-santa

Comment: @Separatrix That was such an epic answer, I remember fondly how I laughed my a** off reading it last year.

Comment: "What procedures should I follow?" Simple - ignore the laws of physics.

Comment: @X-27 or you use multiple santas, then you don't have to violate physics

Comment: To quote the question, "I am the only person in this world who can deliver the toys, I can't delegate it to anybody else"

Comment: Kage Bunshin no Jutsu?

Comment: 1. Put all toys in a (large) box. 2. Attach the box to the sled. 3. Go (fast) with the sled to each kid's house, where you deliver a toy each time. Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: A lot of time traveling involving wormho-- cough cough aurora borealis.

Comment: The other question which is linked as a possible duplicate don't explain well what Santa should do after all in order to deliver the presents. It just says that he would be turned into a liquid trying to do so and have only microsseconds for each kid.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, the answer there covers everything from cargo load to energy consumption and his calorie intake from the cookies. The only thing not covered is the actual order of deliveries which is technically irrelevant as long as he doesn't breach his per child time limit.